Flutter when build the app size comes more than 100mb to 150mb
In Flutter, when I use third-party packages, the app works fine, but when I build my app, the app size comes in at more than 100MB to 150MB. example:   I am using the Agora package for video calls. I just added the package after I tried to build my app size, like 138 MB. What is the solution for this? I want to reduce the app size, and at the same time, I want to use the package.

Agora will make your app size bigger as it is using video rendering libs,
Simple solution is that You can make split APK.

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Extensions/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/340

There are multiple way to reduce app size.
After generating APK click on analysis and look for the size which is taken.

Mostly unused Images or High quality asset will took the place for that try to convert asset to .webp format.

If u use some library that will include it for all architecture that will increase app size.


Solution: In development phase enable following.
In your build.gradle inside defaultConfig add this:
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
}

You can add "x86" if u want to run on emulator
When in production playstore use aab.
